# Cannot find SQL Server Standard for On Premise 2018

Tags: tfs

We are attempting to move from TFS 2015 to TFS 2018 On Premise.  For TFS 2015 we received physical media with a SQL Server 2014 Standard install cd and license key.  For TFS 2018 we had to go through Microsoft Volume Licensing and have our TFS install media but no media or license for SQL Server 2017 Standard.  Has anyone else updated and how did you license SQL Server 2017?

Edit: For those saying I did not research, there is no information on Microsoft's pages for this.  This is the closest you get:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/install/dual-server

> Paid copies of Team Foundation Server come with a license to SQL Server Standard for use with TFS. The Team Foundation Server pricing page explains the details. If you use the license that's included with TFS, you can only use it for the TFS databases.

We are trying to figure out WHERE to go to get this license because it is not on our volume licensing account where the TFS license is.

Comment: I have done as much research as I can.  There is no information on Microsoft's website for this and so far our volume licensing rep has no answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our IT resource eventually found the SQL Server iso download on the volume licensing page.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, you can mark it as the answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is a license issue, you can call 1-800-426-9400, Monday through Friday, 6:00 A.M to 6:00 P.M (Pacific Time) to speak directly to a Microsoft licensing specialist, and you can get more detail information from there. You can also visit the following site for more information and support on licensing issues:

http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/mplahome.mspx